# Magento 2 add custom column into quote table

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to add another column into quote table for Magento 2.

App/Code/[CompanyName]/[Module]/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php

Here's my code:

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup;


class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $connection = $installer->getConnection();
        $connection->addColumn($installer->getTable('quote'), 'can_ship_partially', [
            'type'     => Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment'  => 'Custom can ship partial'
        ]);

        $installer->endSetup();
    }

}//End of class
```

But when I ran `sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade` the column `can_ship_partially` never show up in the quote table. Could someone tell me what did I do wrong please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your code is working well, so I think you Schema-Script is never be called. 
Schema-Scripts are called when modules setup version has been increased.
Check your database, table "module_module" and search for your module entry. Compare the version value with your setup_version value in your module.xml. if the value is the same, try to increase setup_version in your module.xml.